# Induction Argument to prove that the union of a finite number of finite sets is a finite set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give an induction argument to prove that the union of a finite number of finite sets is a finite set. Assume the base case is true as indicated in part(2) of Theorem 1.22

Theorem 1.22: The following results on finite and infinite set are valid.

1. A subset of a finite set is finite.
2. The union of two finite sets is a finite set.
3. A set that contains an infinite subset is infinite.
4. A set that contain an uncountable subset is uncountable.

I have seen some other proofs that solve this without using induction. However, I do not know how to go about proving this using induction.

For the proof am I supposed to let A_k be a finite number of finite sets?

Comment: if you already know that statement 2. is true, you can also use it in the induction step!

Answer (score 0):

After the base case, you would then assume that you have a collection of finite sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$ such that $A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_k$ is finite. This is now your *assumption* and you get to use this as a fact. Then, the induction step would be to suppose that you have another finite set, $A_{k+1}$, and use the previous assumption to show that $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_k\cup A_{k+1}$ is finite.